# How to implement social share in react native?

Tags: react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWqcp.jpg)

```
                    <Button 
                        iconSrc={{ uri: MORE_ICON }}
                        onPress={()=>{
                            this.onCancel()
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                Share.open(shareOptions)
                            },300)
                        }}
                    >
                        Share
                    </Button>
```

> I want to implement a social share in the react-native project, Please provide any reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use react-native API, ref = https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share.html
or 
you can implement npm package ref = https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-share (i have implemented this package, this package is very handy)

Answer (score 1):

There are ways which is possibile to implement the sharing feature.

1) You can use `Share` from `React-Native`

2) You can use [react-native-share](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share) for it.

If you are new in React-Native then please go with the second option.

You just have to install the npm and link it. then you need to write below code to share:

```
            let shareOptions = {
              title: "React Native",
              message: "Message",
              url: "http://facebook.github.io",
              subject: "Share Link" //  for email
            };


            Share.shareSingle(Object.assign(shareOptions, {
              "social": "facebook" // This can be anything
            }));
```

You just need to call the above code when user will do any action.